# Disabling navigation "snapping" when activating pulse engine

Tags: no-mans-sky

In "No Man's Sky" on PC (with Beyond update), when I try to navigate to a location using the pulse engine, my ship's navigation will "snap" to a particular target (if there are any such targets available.)

Most of the time, this feature is useful. However sometimes I really *am* pointing my ship where I want to go, and would rather not have the "snap to" functionality change my navigation. Is there a way to disable this, like a hotkey or something?

For example, this is my current view in my system:

[image: View from the cockpit]

I'm trying to fly to my base as part of my active quest. I have centered my navigation on the base icon, as you can see. If I activate the pulse engine, however, my ship's navigation shifts to the right and refocuses on the space station.

My current workflow is to get most of the way to the space station, drop out of pulse, and re-point at my base. If the two navigational targets are far enough apart at that point, it usually works; sometimes it takes a few tries. I want to avoid this and just fly to my base.

**Is there a built-in way to disable (temporarily or otherwise) the 'snap to' navigational functionality of the pulse engine?** (I'm not playing modded. PC version via Steam, up-to-date.)

Comment: This functionality/feature might have a different name that I'm unaware of, because searching to 'snap to' brought up a whole host of complaints about the pulse engine being too slow or running out of fuel, rather than how it slides the navigational target towards the location it thinks you're actually trying to fly to.

Comment: I was going to make the same question today.  I spent the weekend playing the heck out of NMS, and this was a fairly frustrating issue that I too ran into, on PS4 though.

Comment: Yeah I think it's a general game mechanic, not specific to a particular platform. It was present in the NEXT update as well, but it's much more aggressive in Beyond.

Comment: If two or more target overlaps, then that's indeed unsolved problem in No Man's Sky.  But you don't need to fly at once: make several movements. Turn ship until you are out of that snap radius to anything (or even better you will be snapping to right target) and fly for a while, repeat until snapping works as you want.

Comment: In the screenshot, I'm centered over the target I want. The target it is snapping to is significantly to the right. I should not have to do "several" movements.